# Question about tetration modulus a prime $p>100$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, tetration

Define $x§y$ as the power tower : $x^{x^x...}$ where $...$ means $y$ times.
For instance $2§1=2,2§2=4,2§3=16,2§4=2^{16}$.

See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Let $p$ be a prime larger than $100$.
 Let $n$ be an integer such that $0 < n < p$.

How many residue classes does $2§n$ mod $p$ have ?

Lets define $R(f(n),p$) as the number of residue classes for $f(n)$ mod $p$.

Conjecture : $R(2§n,p)< p - log(p) - slog(p)$

where the $log$ and $slog$ are the base $2$ logarithm and super-logaritm.

See : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm

I got this question from the tetration forum.
It was posted by tommy1729. Below is the link:

http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=833

I assume the conjecture is true and can be much improved. Is this true ?

---

Same question for the strongly related case : $2à1=2$,$2à n = (2à(n-1))$ mod $p$.

---

Answer (score 2):

Let $m$ be *any* natural number atleast 2; there exists a least positive integer $s(m)$ such that $2§s(m) \equiv 2§(s(m)+1) \equiv... mod$ $m$ and $s(m)$ satisfies the inequality $s(m) \leq 1 + s(\phi(m))$ by observing that if $2§s(\phi(m)) \equiv 2§(s(\phi(m))+1) \equiv... mod$ $m$ then by Euler's theorem $2§s(\phi(m)+1) \equiv 2§(s(\phi(m))+2) \equiv... mod$ $m$.

Hence by induction $s(m) \leq $ ceiling$(2log_{2}(m))$. Hence there are atmost ceiling$(2log_{2}(p))$ congruence classes where $p$ is prime.